# fullCalendar only display events on agendaView

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to get the fullCalendar JS application to display events only when on the `agendaView` view, not on the `month` view.

This is my current code. The problem is the `events` function is only called once, on the initial page load. According to documentation (and another site I have with fullCalendar) this function should call every time I change view, or date range. It does not.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: function ( start, end, timezone, callback ) {
        var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
        console.log(view.name);
        if(view.name == 'agendaDay') {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'index.php?events=true',
                data: {
                    start: start,
                    end: end
                },
                async: true,
                success: function ( data ) {
                         callback(data);
                }
            });
        }
    },
    dayClick: function ( date, jsEvent, view ) {
        if(view.name == 'month' && jsEvent.currentTarget.className.indexOf('date-disabled') <= -1) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
        } else if(view.name == 'agendaDay') {
            var check = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            var today = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            if(check > today) {
                alert(date);
            }
        }
    },
    header: {
        left:   'title',
        center: '',
        right:  'today month,agendaDay prev,next'
    },
    dayRender: function ( date, cell ) {
        var check = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        var today = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        if(check <= today) cell[0].className += ' date-disabled';
    }
});
```

I know this for fact as the `console.log` only logs once, the word `month`. So it's only called when I refresh the page, first load it. Not when changing views which it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the `lazyFetching` option. This must be a new option in v2 as I was not expecting it.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/lazyFetching/

My code was correct. I simply needed to tell fullCalendar to get the events at EVERY change of the view and anything else that happened event wise.

```
lazyFetching: false,
```

This now works with my code.